# Replacing characters in Strings with specific logic

Tags: java, string, logic, character

I am currently creating a simple Lexer generator in Java. I am almost finished, ironing out a few bugs here and there, but have come across a problem.

I want to be able to include comment detection in the Lexer, and want to include the comments in a specific way:

- Comments are delimited by any set of characters, stored in a string.

  - Example: `single = "//"`, `multi_beg = "/*"` and `multi_end = "*/"`
- Anything between and including comment characters need to be replaced with whitespace, since the Lexer uses whitespace to detect the gap between tokens. (Replacing with void can possibly cause two tokens to become fused together)

Including such a thing is technically easy, just a couple of booleans and String replacements. However, the Lexer also contains definable String and Character constants. Since comment character(s) can be defined inside these constants, comments can only be "executable" when not currently defining a String or Character.

---

A logic for this might work like the following:

- If currently encased, do nothing, until an uncasing character is found.
- If not encased, and an encasing character is found, encase.
- If not encased, and a **single** line comment is found, replace everything **after** and including the comment characters, with whitespace. (We're dealing with single strings, not arrays, so *everything after* references one line only)
- If not encased, and a **multi** line comment is began, replace everything **after** and including the comment characters, with whitespace, until a multi line comment is **ended**.

---

I have the idea fully marked up in my head, but have no idea how to implement this in Java.

**Note:** I am dealing with a String array, and am thinking of achieving this via enhanced for-loops, processing each line at a time in the Scanner, dealing with comments before tokenising the stack.

```
for (String s : data) {
    // ???
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement this **in Java**?

**Update:** This is what I want my in/out to look like:

[image: Example]

Comment: Are you going to perform manipulations on the input array?Usually lexer splits input in tokens, a new structure, without modifying input. Why can't next token just be a complete string literal?

Comment: @Basilevs I've modulated the lexer into sections. First being the Scanner, second being the Tokeniser. I want to simply "erase" the comments from the string completely, almost as if done with white-out, before displaying the data to the Tokeniser.

Comment: @Basilevs That will be the only manipulation performed so far.

Comment: Now you have two tokenizers for no obvious benefit, don't you?

Comment: @Basilevs No. I want to **remove** data from a string, inside a string array. Once all possible occurrences inside the string array have been **removed**, send the array to be **tokenised**.

Comment: I mean implementation of this removal will use its own tokenizer.

Comment: Have you considered a simple state machine?

Comment: @Basilevs Thats what i'm thinking of, but can't seem to conceive the pseudo-code in my head to do it...

Comment: Do you want streaming API to handle large files? I may implement a prototype, and implementation for streams turns out to be more complex.

Comment: @Basilevs Well since it's all stored in a String array, I guess the limit of lines would be 2^31-1. It's only really for small files, and optimisation is my last worry. What do you think would be the way to go? Thanks for taking the time to implement something for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an untested implementation. Testing is the hardest part, do it very carefully.

```
public class CommentStripper {
    private enum State {
        CODE,
        LINE_COMMENT,
        COMMENT,
        STRING
    }
    public static String strip(String input) {
        return strip(input.toCharArray());
    }

    public static String strip(char[] input) {
        State currentState = State.CODE;
        StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
        char[] lineSeparator = System.lineSeparator().toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            STATE_SWITCH: switch (currentState) {
            case CODE: 
                if (input[i] == '"') {
                    currentState = State.STRING;
                    rv.append(input[i]);
                    break;
                }
                if (input[i] == '/') {
                    if (i + 1 >= input.length) {
                        rv.append(input[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    if (input[i+1] == '*') {
                        i++;
                        currentState = State.COMMENT;
                        break;
                    } else if (input[i+1] == '/') {
                        i++;
                        currentState = State.LINE_COMMENT;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                rv.append(input[i]);
            break;
            case STRING:
                if (input[i] == '"') {
                    currentState = State.CODE;
                    rv.append(input[i]);
                    break;
                }
                rv.append(input[i]);
                break;
            case COMMENT:
                if (input[i] == '*') {
                    if (i + 1 >= input.length) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (input[i + 1] == '/') {
                        i++;
                        currentState = State.CODE;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case LINE_COMMENT:
                for (int sepIndex = 0; sepIndex < lineSeparator.length; sepIndex++) {
                    if (input[i+sepIndex] != lineSeparator[sepIndex]) {
                        break STATE_SWITCH;
                    }
                }
                i+=lineSeparator.length-1;
                rv.append(lineSeparator);
                currentState = State.CODE;
                break;
            } 
        }
        return rv.toString();
    }
}
```

Initial tests:

```
import static commentStrip.CommentStripper.strip;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CommentStripperTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("\"test\"", strip("\"test\"//hello\"test\""));
        assertEquals("\"test\"\"test\"", strip("\"test\"/*hello*/\"test\""));
        assertEquals("test"+System.lineSeparator()+"test", strip("test//linecomment"+System.lineSeparator()+"test"));
        assertEquals("test", strip("test/*test"));
        assertEquals("\"test//hellotest\"", strip("\"test//hellotest\""));
        assertEquals("\"test/*hello*/test\"", strip("\"test/*hello*/test\""));
    }

}
```

Minimalistic array-based approach was chosen for its efficiency. Streaming API makes this either bloated or ineffective. You will have to concatenate your strings to use this.

Note that there is no way to put an escaped quote in a string literal. This was not specified by your question, so I omitted handling of this.

Consider using parsing libraries like ANTLR instead of writing parsers yourself.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Have been at work recently and really busy. I modified it for my generator and works great. Thanks alot. As for ANTLR, maybe I'll hook the generator into it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Usual approach is to leave this job to tokenizer and make comments to be a kind  of whitespace token.

Comment: I understand, but I don't want a token at all. I want it removed before any data is pushed to the tokeniser, way back in the Scanner section.

Comment: Why do you want it to be this way?

Comment: I've written my Lexer with a structure of scanning through tokens, stopping to tokenise it only if it is a symbol, digit or character. If its a symbol, map it to its corresponding character, and spit out a token. Digit, spit out a number or real. Alphabetical/Constant Char, spit out an identifier or a string/char. Whitespaces are skipped.